# Summing multiple cells that match row AND column criteria?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been given a file with 2 years worth of dates as column headers and sales info below.  There's also a column that contains Year data.  I'm trying to sort by both Year and Day of the Week.  I'm about 4 hours in, and can't seem to solve this one, so any help would be greatly appreciated!  I know I could filter by year, sum the columns, and HLOOKUP each day of the week -- I just figured there's a way to do this with an array formula that would simplify things.

Comment: Have you added a column that makes a composite key of Year and Day of the Week by combining them like `=A2&B2`? Then you can use `=sumif()` elsewhere to pull just the matching values by creating a matching key, perhaps from the row and column headings of another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usually use `SUMPRODUCT` for this - I'm not quite clear on the criteria for you but generically you can use this setup

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10=Z1)*(B1:J1=Z2),B2:J10)`

where `A2:A10` are the row labels, `B1:J1` column headers and `B2:J10` the data. Note the data range must be the same width as the column headers and same height as the row labels

`Z1` and `Z2` contain the criteria - you can use cell refs or put the criteria directly in the formula

If you can't adjust that then post back with more details

Comment: And now I know why they call you Houdini...  I had no idea you could use sumproduct like this!