# Excel - how to select columns with dates for array calculation?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

can't wrap my mind around this one. We have data in a sheet with columns with a date header (Jun 2017,Jul 2017,Aug 2017) and these are 'rolling headers' (they give information from the current date - Now in March the first month shown is April 2017 - In April the first header will be May 2017. 
I need to be able to sum the cost in those column based on a certain period, like giving the total for a full year two years from a given date. I tried the below, but it gives me a #Value error

```
=SUMIFS(Calc1!EZ2:HR10000,Calc1!EZ1:HR1,">"&DATE((YEAR(Calc1!EX2)+2),1,1),Calc1!EZ1:HR1,"<"&DATE((YEAR(Calc1!EX2)+3),1,1))
```

Also marking it as an array formula gives me the same result.

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way (use aggregate?).

Thanks, Rene

Comment: Are your date headers true dates or are they test that look like dates?

Comment: Hi Scott, they are true dates.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot or an example?

Comment: Nov 17 Dec 17 Jan 18 Feb 18 Mar 18
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
75 75 75 0 75
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 75 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0

Comment: @Yass, can't copy the info in or show the snip.....

Comment: @Scott Craner - real dates, not text

Comment: OK, thanks very much for all your help. Got the grey cells working!! Finally found out that in the big data field there was a value error; once corrected everything started working :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=sumproduct((--(Calc1!EZ1:HR1>DATE((YEAR(Calc1!EX2)+2),1,1)))*(--(Calc1!EZ1:HR1<DATE((YEAR(Calc1!EX2)+3),1,1)))*(--(Calc1!EZ2:EZ10000<>"")),Calc1!EZ2:HR10000)
```

Sumproduct can sum the array reference (rows and columns) for a condition in header rows and header columns which is your case (sum the cells in the column if the header matches the condition)
all you have to do is create a criteria for rows (so the formula can define number of rows), I just used:
`Calc1!EZ2:EZ10000<>""`  you can create another condition for rows just to make the sumproduct recognize the rows, since the initial condition for Date will recongnize the columns, when the 2 conditions are met the cell will be add and you will have the result
Sumifs works when each criteria has the same number of rows as the other criterias, which is not the case your criteria is the Headers of columns (Calc1!EZ1:HR1) which is different from your whole array (Calc1!EZ2:HR10000)

Your question is like [Superuser question 895987](https://superuser.com/questions/895987/summing-multiple-cells-that-match-row-and-column-criteria) and this question has the answer you need

Comment: thanks, really appreciate your support. Regretfully I still get a value error with that formula. Appreciate your comment re Sumifs size.

Comment: I get "A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type"

Comment: Calc1!EZ2:EZ10000 should be number, Calc1!EZ1:HR1 custom date (mmm yy), EX2 should be date, Calc1!EZ2:HR10000 numbers

Comment: I'm pulling data from another system that comes across as cell type 'General'. Thought that just multiplying it with 1 would make it a number, but that doesn't seem to be the case. :-(

Comment: Try to sum those numbers just by using Sum only and see if you get error or value...

Answer (score 1):

Hey Rene I would like to suggest some examples related to your query:

---

`=SUMIFS(C2:C9, B2:B9, ">=10/1/2014", B2:B9, "<=10/31/2014")`,

This will Sum values which falls between October 10 and October 31st.

---

`=SUMIFS(C2:C9, B2:B9, ">="&B2, B2:B9, "<="&B7)`

Above is dynamic formula where in place of date, cell address has been used. 
Hope this help you.